# Django: mutate queryset to another model on the fly

Tags: python, django

Is there a more elegant/faster way to do this?

Here are my models:

```
class X(Model):
    (...)

class A(Model):
    xs = ManyToManyField(X)

class B(A):
    (...)

class C(A): # NOTE: not relevant here
    (...)

class Y(Model):
    b = ManyToOneField(B)
```

Here is what I want to do:

```
def foo(x):
    # NOTE: b's pk (b.a_ptr) is actually a's pk (a.id)
    return Y.objects.filter(b__in=x.a_set.all())
```

But it returns the following error:

```
<repr(<django.db.models.query.QuerySet at 0x7f6f2c159a90>) failed:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'a_ptr'
into field. Choices are: ...enumerate all fields of A...>
```

And here is what I'm doing right now in order to minimize the queries:

```
def foo(x):
    a_set = x.a_set
    a_set.model = B # NOTE: force the model to be B
    return Y.filter(b__in=a_set.all())
```

It works but it's not one line. It would be cool to have something like this:

```
def foo(x):
    return Y.filter(b__in=x.a_set._as(B).all())
```

The simpler way in Django seems to be the following:

```
def foo(x):
    return Y.filter(b__in=B.objects.filter(pk__in=x.a_set.all()))
```

...but this makes useless sub-queries in SQL:

```
SELECT Y.* FROM Y WHERE Y.b IN (
    SELECT B.a_ptr FROM B WHERE B.a_ptr IN (
        SELECT A.id FROM A WHERE ...));
```

This is what I want:

```
SELECT Y.* FROM Y WHERE Y.b IN (SELECT A.id FROM A WHERE ...);
```

(This SQL example is a bit simplified because the relation between A and X is actually a ManyToMany table, I substituted this with `SELECT A.id FROM A WHERE ...` for clarity sake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get a better result if you follow the relationship one more step, rather than using `in`.

```
Y.objects.filter(b__xs=x)
```

Comment: It actually works pretty well. Thanks. Only one query is made using three inner join. No sub-query. Perfect

Answer (score 0):

I know next to nothing about databases, but there are many warnings in the Django literature about concrete inheritance `class B(A)` causing database inefficiency because of repeated INNER JOIN operations.

The underlying problem is that relational databases aren't object-orientated.

If you use Postgres, then Django has native support (from 1.8) for Hstore fields, which are searchable but schema-less collections of keyword-value pairs. I intend to be using one of these in my base class (your A) to eliminate any need for derived classes (your B and C). Instead, I'll maintain a type field in A (equal to "B" or "C" in your example) and use that and/or careful key presence checking to access subfields of the Hstore field which are "guaranteed" to exist if (say) instance.type=="C" (which constraint isn't enforced at the DB integrity level).

I also discovered the *django-hstore* module which existed prior to Django 1.8, and which has even greater functionality. I've yet to do anything with it so cannot comment further.

I also found reference to wide tables in the literature, where you simply define a model A with a potentially large number of fields which contain useful data only if the object is of type B, and more yet fields for types C,D,... I don't have the DB knowledge to assess the cost of lots of blank or null fields attached to every row of a table. Clearly if you have a million sheep records and one pedigree-racehorse record and one stick-insect record, as "subclasses" of Animal in the same wide table, it gets silly.

I'd appreciate feedback on either idea if you have the DB understanding that I lack.

Oh, and for completeness, there's the *django-polymorphic* module, but that builds on concrete inheritance with its attendant inefficiencies.